# Transform A LOGICAL expression into a Json using Jquery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to develop a function in javascript/jQuery which takes the following kinds of inputs i.e. Logical expressions and the respective expected responses as shown below:

1. Input: ((1==Yes)&&(3==No))|| (5==Permanent)

   ```
   Response:
   {
       condition:"OR"
       {
           condition: "AND"{
               rules:[{
                   Question: 1,
                   Operator:"==",
                   Response:"Yes"
               },
               {
                   Question: 3,
                   Operator:"==",
                   Response:"No"
               }]
           }
           rules:[{
               Question: 5,
               Operator:"==",
               Response:"Permanent"
           } ]
       }
   }
   ```

I've tried some other ways like finding the root operator i.e. && or || and then finding the operands. But the input might vary..and the constructed Json should be similar to the one as shown above.

Hope I've made it clear
Thank you

Comment: Please edit the question and show us what you have tried

Comment: `rules:{..},{..}` uh, is this even valid json..?